# Условие и регулярное выражение javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
function cut_or_add(obj)
{
    val = $('get_div').value;
    replace = val.replace(new RegExp(obj, 'g'), '');
    $('get_div').value = replace;
    // сие вырезает значение obj из val
}
```

Как определить что значение obj отсутствует в val и добавить его туда? Мне нужно только определить его отсутствие. Подскажите как будет выглядеть условие на основе регулярного выражения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!val.match('/regexp/g');
```

не?

Ну, в вашем случае -

```
if(!val.match(new RegExp(obj, 'g'))){
  //Отсутствует
}
```

Правда, я думаю, вы и сами догадались

Comment: Пошел юзать)

Comment: Премного благодарен, работает как и нужно было)